# Convert integer to binary using 2 functions - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working through Zybooks C859: Introduction to Programming in Python.

I have a practical lab where the prompt is:

Write a program that takes in a positive integer as input, and outputs a string of 1's and 0's representing the integer in binary. For an integer x, the algorithm is:
As long as x is greater than 0
Output x % 2 (remainder is either 0 or 1)
x = x // 2
Note: The above algorithm outputs the 0's and 1's in reverse order. You will need to write a second function to reverse the string.

Ex: If the input is: 6

the output is: 110

The program must define and call the following two functions. Define a function named int_to_reverse_binary() that takes an integer as a parameter and returns a string of 1's and 0's representing the integer in binary (in reverse). Define a function named string_reverse() that takes an input string as a parameter and returns a string representing the input string in reverse.
def int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value)
def string_reverse(input_string)

I am failing unit tests despite getting the correct output with every input I've tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value):
    binary =''
    while integer_value > 0: #as long as
        binary = binary + str(integer_value % 2) #modulo
        integer_value = integer_value // 2 #new x assignment
    return binary
def string_reverse(input_string):
    return input_string[::-1]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    integer_value = int(input())
    
    input_string = int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value)
    solution = string_reverse(input_string)
    print(solution)
```

Comment: for which input it is failing ?  You can handle case of 0 when integer_value==0 then return 0

Comment: `string_reverse()` function can be simplified with a single line: `return  input_string[::-1]`. It does not need to and should not call `int_to_reverse_binary()` function.

Comment: Why are you calling `int_to_reverse_binary` in the global scope and within `string_reverse`?  The way you have it now, should fail every test

Comment: In regards to calling int_to_reverse_binary. That was a mistake however, it wasn't preventing the code from running. I made the suggested change by Haoliang.

Still not passing all the unit tests despite the output being "correct".

Unfortunately Zybooks doesn't share a whole lot of feedback on the failed unit tests.

Comment: can you share the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

```
def int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value):
    output = ''
    while integer_value > 0:
        output += str(integer_value % 2)
        integer_value //= 2
    return output

def string_reverse(input_string):
    return input_string[::-1]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    integer_value = int(input())
    input_string = int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value)
    print(string_reverse(input_string))
```

Comment: Hey @snuffy, please consider adding an explanation on how your code helps solving the problem of the original question / what is done differently.